# jQuery image switcher not loading an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, prettyphoto

I want to create an image switcher in jQuery. I want the switcher to close the current div when the right or left arrow is pressed and then let it click a different link which will open a new div. **I have a problem because when the click event happens the image does not load. Loading animation goes forever.**

Here is the HTML code of the list in which there is a `a.zoom` element, which shall be clicked after closing the first div. Closing of the div is done by clicking the close button: `a.pp_close`:

```
<ul class="products product-grid clearfix">




<li class="post-9 product type-product status-publish first  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-1/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/eff4f0268af2bf49ffc913b6e5c78dca1-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Globus 1">              
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/eff4f0268af2bf49ffc913b6e5c78dca1.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-1/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-1/">Globus 1</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Globus z mapą przedstawiającą zdjęcie satelitarne ziemi.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">650,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=9" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="9" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>            </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>



<li class="post-16 product type-product status-publish  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-2/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ac137512137aba2e02d45af4a1d525bb11-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="globus_2">             
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ac137512137aba2e02d45af4a1d525bb11.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-2/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-2/">Globus 2</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Wyjątkowy model przedstawiający gwiazdozbiory opisane po łacinie.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">650,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=16" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="16" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>          </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>



<li class="post-20 product type-product status-publish last  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-3/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/41879e5271410602be3970f18dd7d49911-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="globus_3">             
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/41879e5271410602be3970f18dd7d49911.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-3/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-3/">Globus 3</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Model w kolorze piaskowym przedstawiający mapę polityczną.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">635,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=20" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="20" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>          </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>



<li class="post-23 product type-product status-publish first  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-4/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dd2db71261e9862748fbfc66fbcfccdf1-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="globus_4">              
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dd2db71261e9862748fbfc66fbcfccdf1.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-4/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-4/">Globus 4</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Globus w kolorze czarno-srebrnym obrazujący mapę polityczną świata.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">635,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=23" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="23" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>          </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>



<li class="post-26 product type-product status-publish  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-5/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/f5db3e9cb77d18f52f558f96a0a4836f3-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="globus_5">              
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/f5db3e9cb77d18f52f558f96a0a4836f3.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-5/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-5/">Globus 5</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Model przedstawia mapę geograficzną świata na błękitnym tle oceanów.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">635,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=26" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="26" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>          </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>



<li class="post-28 product type-product status-publish last  product taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-globusy-male-11-5 instock"> 
    <div>        <figure> 

            <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-6/">

                <img width="252" height="160" src="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/185dcd4ee1abc9aed84c9de4a60ca40d3-252x160.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="globus_6">              
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/185dcd4ee1abc9aed84c9de4a60ca40d3.jpg" class="zoom"></a>
                <a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-6/" class="link"></a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <div class="detail">         
            <h4><a href="http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/produkt/globus-6/">Globus 6</a></h4>



<div class="excerpt_styling">Pięknie wykonany globus ukazujący aktualną mapę polityczną świata.</div>




            <span><span class="amount">635,00zł</span></span>

            <div class="icon">
                <a href="/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/?add-to-cart=28" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="28" data-product_sku="10" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple tooltip"></a>          </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>


                </ul>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39)
            if( $('#fullResImage').length > 0 ) {
                $('a.pp_close').click();
                $('body > div.product_wrap > div > div > div.span9.woocommerce > ul > li.post-16 > div > figure > div > a.zoom').click();
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: `'body > div.product_wrap > div > div > div.span9.woocommerce > ul > li.post-16 > div > figure > div > a.zoom'` great selector

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4L2ED/ or share your link if it is in live website

Comment: That's a temprorary selector. Should work on one page. After that I will add an universal one.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little lost, not sure how to use jsfiddle

Comment: http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/

This is the website URL as requested.

Comment: For that exact selector I used you have to visit this exact subpage:

http://www.globusy.eu/sklep/kategoria-produktu/globusy-male-11-5/

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL - In case you don't see my comments here anymore (it sometimes fails for me) I tag you in this comment.